# What can i use to create db scheme in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I want to create db scheme in eclipse, but dont know what can i use for this. I try ERMaster http://ermaster.sourceforge.net/content/manual/en/index.html#3.1. . But it looks terrible. Can you tell me simple plug in for eclipse what can import db and show it's scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ER-diagram-editor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-erd/) for eclipse

[DB-schema-viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbschemaviewer/) for eclipse

Also [this](http://www.myeclipseide.com/module-htmlpages-display-pid-16.html) one isn't bad, but is not a plugin or extension for eclipse.

Comment: How i can see  ER-diagram-editor create ER diagrams not db schemes. Or im wrong?

Comment: with the second one (MyEclipse Database Explorer Perspective) you can also create db schema

Comment: If you want a plugin for eclipse try this http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbschemaviewer/

Comment: For DB shema viewer i gonna install GEF?

Comment: At the e\end i make scheme in Paint.

Answer (score 1):

[Jailer](http://jailer.sourceforge.net/) isn't an Eclipse plug-in but it is great for visualizing database tables.

Comment: I will try it, but want something what is eclipse plug in.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following steps will solve for your request.

1. download jar file from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-erd/).
2. copy it in to the eclipse drop-in folder (example path: C:\eclipse\dropins).
3. restart eclipse.
4. then go through ***File->New->Other->ERMaster*** and create ER file.

   Here is my reference [link](http://nverma-tech-blog.blogspot.com/2015/03/ermaster-creating-entity-relationship.html)